# What is the React equivalent of an Angular directive that only works on attributes?

Tags: angularjs-directive, reactjs

For example you could have a directive in angular like so:

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('classy', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $el) {
       $el.addClass('stay-classy');
    }
  }
}
```

And implement like so:

```
<div classy></div>
```

There doesn't seem to be an equivalent in React that I've seen after reading through most the docs and googling. I was hoping for something like:

```
...
render: function() {
  return (
     <MyComponent classy></MyComponent>
  );
}
```

Is there something like that possible that I've been missing? Is there a different yet functionally similar equivalent? Or maybe this question just shows that I'm missing some part of the "React way" and I shouldn't ever want to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could take a few steps back and tell us what problem you're trying to solve. *Why* do you want to use s `<div>` with an attribute instead of a component?

Comment: Angular has a lot of stuff that's only needed due to other flaws in angular. Attribute and class directives are necessitated by nearly everything in angular, from required mutability to reliance on what html provides, rather than js. It's not something you need in react.

Comment: @Jordan I don't have a specific use case in mind, so I guess this more of a general question. I think one benefit of an "attribute" component/directive is the ability to combine multiple component functionalities without explicitly defining a new component. As an example, maybe you have a dropdown component and a tooltip component. Now, I want a dropdown that shows a tooltip on hover. In Angular, you could combine those 2 functionalities on a single element, i.e. `<dropdown tooltip="help text"></dropdown>`

Comment: With `<MyComponent classy></MyComponent>`, `classy` is a property not an attribute. React whitelists HTML attributes currently, and anything not in that list and not prefixed with `data-` is passed as a property instead. Inside the component it can be accessed via `this.props.classy`. JSX transforms `classy` into `classy=true` to match the effect of HTML boolean attributes.

Comment: @ccnokes That's understandable, but my counter would be: Is defining a new directive really any different from, or better than, defining a new component?

Comment: Yes, we're talking *Decoration*. What we're all expecting is that instead of having `<Items />` and pull in `<ItemDecoratorA />` (as we add "responsibilities" we have ...A...B...C), which could be excessive for some meager responsibilities, we instead have something along the lines of a `focusOn` which may only have a single method/handler. Instead of `<Items />` having to pull in every correct decorator -- or maintain the parent-decorator -- we just change `<ItemDecoratorABC />.` to `<Item a b c />`. **This is one thing Angular nailed as is how native HTML ClassNames work -- just Decorators**

Comment: @Cody Well said. That captures the essence of what I was trying to say above to Jordan. "Is defining a new directive really any different from, or better than, defining a new component?" -- No, of course not, but being able to compose multiple components' functionality via decoration (not creating new "combo" components or something) is more elegant, and something I wish React had. Thanks all for the comments.

Comment: @ccnokes, you bet. I think this is a great enough void in the framework that a pattern or plugin will come along. Until then, I'm using the Template Method Pattern to mitigate entropy throughout my apps. Something like: `method () { /* do stuff */; this._method.call(this, ...); }` along with `componentWillMount () { SomeDecorator.apply(this); }`. I know that's kind of cryptic, but check out Template Method and you might come up with something better than how I'm implementing it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It will be helpful to consider what Angular and React are each doing "behind the scenes."

In your Angular example, when you write `<div classy/></div>` you're saying "render a DIV element and then attach to it the behaviors defined by the `classy` directive.

In your React example, when you write `<MyComponent classy></MyComponent>`, you're saying, "create an instance of MyComponent and pass it the props `{ classy: true }`. The transpiler (Babel or whathaveyou) will turn it into the following JavaScript:

```js
React.createElement(MyComponent, { classy: true });
```

So the answer to your question is that you can't write `<MyComponent classy></MyComponent>` because `MyComponent` component doesn't know what to do with the `classy` prop. In React, you might write something like this instead:

```js
class ClassyDiv extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { className, ...rest } = this.props;
    return <div className={`${className || ''} stay-classy`} {...rest}/>;
  }
}
```

This works because we know the `React.DOM.div` component (like most DOM components) knows what to do with the `className` prop.

Since React 0.14 we can express something like this more simply, as a "pure" stateless functional component, i.e. a function that accepts props and returns the rendered result:

```js
function AlsoClassyDiv(props) {
  const { className, ...rest } = props;
  return <div className={`${className || ''} stay-classy`} {...rest}/>;
};
```

You can see both approaches in action in the below snippet.

```js
class ClassyDiv extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { className, ...rest } = this.props;
    return <div className={`${className || ''} stay-classy`} {...rest}/>;
  }
}

function AlsoClassyDiv({ className, ...props }) {
  return <div className={`${className || ''} stay-classy`} {...props}/>;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div id="container">
    <div>Regular div</div>
    <ClassyDiv>ClassyDiv!</ClassyDiv>
    <AlsoClassyDiv>AlsoClassyDiv!</AlsoClassyDiv>
  </div>,
  document.body
);
```

```css
.stay-classy { font: bold 3em Helvetica; text-shadow: 4px 4px 2px #aaa; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: +1 for "in Angular you write HTML and then Angular attaches behaviors to it, but in React you write components...and React generates DOM elements from them". That's a good explanation that illustrates one of the fundamental principles of React and I think would be helpful for anyone transitioning from Angular to React. Thanks!

Comment: "they're really just JavaScript—and React generates DOM elements from them" - So basically they are components that represent DOM elements, yet they are not DOM elements, they only result into DOM elements. Dude.. React's inverse thinking got to you.

Comment: I wouldn't call it high order component at all, your example is just simple specialization by parent component. High order component is slightly different patern...

Comment: @StanislavŠolc It's worth noting that this answer was written pre-React 0.14. Would you say that the following, an equivalent React 0.14 pure function component, is a HOC? ``const ClassyDiv = props => <div className={`${props.className || ''} stay-classy`}/>;``

Comment: @StanislavŠolc To clarify, I'm asking sincerely. I think you're right that my answer is a bit muddled with regard to HOCs, so if you have any suggestions on how to improve it I'd appreciate it. Can I clarify the bit about HOCs or should I omit it entirely?

Comment: In angular you can attach multiple directives on elements, is this possible in react?

e.g.

<div draggableEl="" highlightOnMouseDown trackOnEvent="click">Drag me!</div>

Comment: There is no equivalent in React this is a feature only Angular has, the example in this answer does not cover the full context of how directive's work in Angular I could add 'classy' to any element without the need to pass props down.

Answer (score 7):

One way you could implement similar behavior is using React class mixins

Comment: Sounds like Mixins are on their way out -- but (+1) for stating what nobody else has even glanced on.

Answer (score 4):

A great example of a useful directive in angular is

```
<a href="#target" class="smooth-scroll">Target</a>
```

The smoothScroll directive would intercept the click event then use window scroll or jquery scrollTo to apply all manner of animation.

Anywhere in the html one could then simply use the directive powered class name.

This sort of thing is not available in React. To do it in React you would have to create a special link component to use instead of:

```
<a> like ASmooth....
```

Comment: While I agree with you on "To do it in React you would have to create a special link component", in Angular(/JS) you have to create a special attribute directive to attach this behavior to your anchor element. At the same time, your newly created special React link component could render an anchor element in the end as well, with the same behavior attached to it. In the end we get the same result, potatos potatoes.

Comment: @BrunoFinger The whole point of directives is composability. First: you can apply a directive to any component, even components included from other libraries. Second: you can apply multiple directives to the same component. Directives are decorators, so it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking to find a way to reproduce the directive system for applying style  or play with the component.

You can create a component that play with children and then render them :

```
function TextCenter(props) {

  // Iterates over children and clone it with custom props
  const children = React.Children.map(
    props.children,
    (child) => React.cloneElement(child, { className: 'text-center' }
  )

  // Render the children
  return <>{children}</>;
}

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <TextCenter>
      <div>
        <h1>Hello centered world</h1>
        <p>Yessss</p>
      </div>
    </TextCenter>
  )
}
```

Here is a more powerfull example for responsive text alignement :

```
interface Props extends Breakpoints<'start' | 'center' | 'end'>{}

export const TextAlign: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  const className = generateClassName('text', props);
  const children = React.Children.map(props.children, child => React.cloneElement(child as ReactElement, { className }))

  return (
    <>
      {children}
    </>
  )
}

export const MyComponent: FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <TextCenter xs="center" md="start">
        <h1>I am centered on mobile but not on desktop</h1>
      </TextCenter>
    </div>
  )
}
```

> There are two problems with this solution, when the children is a component, it must also have the prop `className` and it also makes the HTML less clean as it adds a level in hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Look my friend i didn't get you well but long story short, angularJS directives is actually a component. So the idea behind angularJs directive is to create component that has its own scope data and it's own method to operate on it. I was thinking the same way you did and found your post here and i couldn't find an answer for that. But thanks for working experience, i thought about it and know how to do it.

I wanted to add an edit button for each link item in a list to toggle the edit form for each one only so each ListItem should be a stand alone component, that way i have standalone state for each one and i toggle it on & off.

[image]