# alternative for attribute directives (angularjs) in react

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, reactjs

I just moved from directives in AngularJS to using components in React and I have came across an issue.
In Angular I used attributes directives, for example a directive that would add Google Analytics events to elements in the DOM, or automatically apply multi-line ellipsis.
Is there a similar alternative in react, not necessarily attribute directive but maybe a best practice?

Thanks.

Comment: No. There is no attribute level component as such . Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30408586/what-is-the-react-equivalent-of-an-angular-directive-that-only-works-on-attribut

Comment: See [React.cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement). You can also wrap components w/ others that add logic to them.

Comment: One more reason to not to choose React.